# Securing 3rd Party Ads

Tags: advertisement-server

I want to switch over to using secure Apache webservers. I did some testing, I can get my AdServer to serve to HTTPS:// as the creative is hosted by me the adtag is mine and so is the clickthru..

However all 3rd party tags pop up the "content not secure...." box... Can I secure it?

I can't really find anyone who's successfully done this, and I'm beinging to think that you can't...

Comment: Can you explain more about your question?

Comment: Hi,

Sure ... I've installed apache 2061 on a couple of sun solaris; so all the tags that on my webpage are now my adtags are https:// so when users are on a secure they don't get "This page contains both secure and nonsecureitems..."

Comment: The adtags allow the delivery of images from my AdServer, sometimes we have 3rd party tags which have jsut a redirect in front of our adtags which give the pop-up

Comment: and also this means that the images is unsecure and it makes the page unverable to attack...  

But I don't think I can make the 3rd party tags secure...

Answer (score 0):

> However all 3rd party tags pop up the "content not secure...." box... Can I secure it?

Only if you're using an advertising network that provides ads over HTTPS. Everything has to be HTTPS, including scripts, iframes and the final images used. Many networks don't give you this ability, but you'd have to check with the specific provider you're using.

You could theoretically stop the error message by having ad content appearing to come from your server, which is actually behaving as a proxy, but:

- most ad networks would view that very suspiciously; it would look like you were committing click fraud, and
- it's not actually “secure” — those errors don't appear for no reason! If there were a man-in-the-middle between your server and the ad network, they could inject content like scripts into your ad sources, compromising your site's own security through an XSS-like attack.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to ask your thirdparties for Secure Tags.  99% of adversers should be able to do this.  I know for sure that both Atlas and Doubleclick can generate secure tags.